# Formatting of @HtmlTextBoxFor MVC Visual Basic Webpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.textboxfor

This is my first post here although I use this forum all the time and it usually provides me with a solution, however I've searched all over the web for an answer to this and I can't find anything.
I'm developing a website which provides software support. Users log on to it and add a "support call" which a member of a support team will answer.

The problem I am facing is that when users describe their problem (inside the TextBoxFor shown below), they can type out their problem, and format the text as they please, however when the call is submitted, sometimes (it appears randomly) the formatting just disappears, e.g. some spacing and paragraph use just disappears, here is an example:

### Correct formatting:

```
Hi I'm having difficulty with x, and y and I need some assistance.
      Could somebody help me out?
```

### How it appears sometimes:

```
Hi I'm having difficulty with x,and y and I need some assistance.Could somebody help me out?"
```

This, of course is highly simplified, and some people have to write many paragraphs and text lines.

Here is the code for the textbox (in the view):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.SupportCall.Subject, New With {.maxLength =            "254", .style = "width:500px;"})
```

It is worth mentioning that when a support call is submitted, it goes to a folder which is picked up by another internal piece of software, which then creates a database record for the call, meaning that an email notification can be sent to the support team, then the list of calls to be answered is updated from that database model, therefore I'm pretty sure it's possible that this process could be what is changing the text formatting.

A reason why this is happening is just as useful as a solution to me so any input is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 <pre></pre>
```

prepend and append it.

Comment: I've added this, everything is working as before, however I can't test it personally as internal stuff won't go through the system like an external call would, so only time will tell.

Comment: Sadly I don't think that's worked :( The help is much appreciated though buddy!